# plotting number in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have temperature data store in this order and I want to calculate the temperature difference in vertical on each minute

```
timestamp        high    tempVirt
04/05/2019 10:02    100      36.0
                    150      35.5 
                    200      35.6 
04/05/2019 10:03    100      36.2
                    150      35.7
                    200      35.8
04/05/2019 10:04    100      36.0
                    150      35.2
                    200      35.3 
04/05/2019 10:05    100      36.1 
                    150      35.5 
                    200      35.5
```

This is how I calculate it:

````
#Calculating temperature difference with respect to the first height in each
df["tempdiff"] = 0
j = 0
for i in range(len(df)-1):
    if df.iloc[i,0] == grouped_first.iloc[j,0]:
        df.loc[i,"tempdiff"] = df.loc[i,"tempVirt"] - grouped_first.loc[j,"tempVirt"]
    else:
        j += 1
        df.loc[i,"tempdiff"] = df.loc[i,"tempVirt"] - grouped_first.loc[j,"tempVirt"] ```
````

How to make a plot in form of number instead of color?this is how the plot that I want
[temperature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVgzy.png)

Comment: ` a plot in form of number instead of color` - can you explain or add an example picture?

Comment: Can you add an expected results?

Comment: I have added a picture on my question